# typescript intellisense issue for constructor overload

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I'm trying to write an plugin with typescript. I declared an interface like this:

```
interface Options {
  options1: string,
  options2: number,
  options3: boolean,
  ...
}
```

And also, I used it as the options this exported class may take and overload it:

```
export class MyClass {
    constructor(public options: Options = {} as Options) {
        // options which can be overload
        let {
            /* default options: */
            option1 = 'option1',
            option2 = 2,
            option3 = true,
            ...
        }: Options = options as Options;
        // overload
        this.options.option1 = option1;
        this.options.option2 = option2;
        this.options.option3 = option3;
    }
}
```

Finally I instantiate it.

```
const class1 = new MyClass({
    ...
})
```

I'm using the vscode as my editor. And it doesn't make sense to me that the intellisense only offer me with the hint like this:

> MyClass(options?: Options)

I thought it should be like this:

> MyClass(options?: {options1: string, options2: number ... })

Anybody know why this happen, and how to make the intellisense works as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue at TypeScript tracking this. But one issue with this approach is when the option is long, it does not give you the full detail anyway.

It is actually working quite well now. What you can do is this:

```
const class1 = new MyClass({
  // [Ctrl+space] here
})
```

It will actually list the option properties `option1`, `option2` etc with IntelliSense.

Comment: Thx! [Ctrl+space] gets what I want. Hope this issue shall fixed later.